# Series Grouping SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following data in the dataset

```
Key Assignee Sev InOps InTek
 1   A         1 Y   Y
 2   B         2 Y   N
 3   C         3 N   Y
```

Need to plot the chart as follows so that I get

Sev on X Axis
Count(Key) on Y
Assignee belongs to Ops (Y) as Ops bar
Assignee belongs to Tek(Y) as Tek bar -For each severity we will have two bars then , one for Ops and another for Tek
which will show as follows

```
Sev 1 Ops Tek
      1    1

Sev2  1    0
Sev3  0    1
```

I have the chart configuration done as follows

In Count I have dragged the Key column
In Category group I have the Sev column
in the series group , do I need to put two series opscolumn and tek respectively ?

Comment: Do you have any control over that Dataset, i.e. can you change its structure if you need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this, if possible, would be to pivot the data when generating the Dataset, i.e. having something like this:

[image]

From here it's trivial to create the Chart - Series based on `InType`, Category based on `Severity` and the data is a Count of `Key`.

If you can't pivot your data, create a Chart like this:

[image]

The expression for the first Chart Series is:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!InOps.Value = "Y", 1, 0))
```

and the second:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!InTek.Value = "Y", 1, 0))
```

It's also useful to set a custom Legend text for each of the Series:

[image]

[image]

Either way, you get the required result:

[image]